# git: track a folder but ignore a folder within it

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I'm trying everything but without success. I have a folder A, with folder B,C and D within it. I want to track B and C and ignore D.
I tried:

```
.gitignore file:

A/D
```

it doesn't work. Git keeps ignoring the whole A folder.
How can I do it?

Comment: Are folders B and C empty? Git only adds non-empty folders. Your `.gitignore` worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.gitignore` worked for me. It was hard to explain in the comment above. Here's more info..
Note: Empty directories are ignored.

```
mkdir -p foo/A/B foo/A/C foo/A/D  
touch  foo/A/B/bar foo/A/C/bar foo/A/D/bar  
cd foo  
echo 'A/D' > .gitignore  
git init
git add .  
git status  
new file: .gitignore  
new file: A/B/bar  
new file: A/C/bar
```